# Point cloud texture mapping

Tags: mesh, point-clouds

I imported a mesh 3d scan and made it into point cloud model using geo nodes mesh to point,[image] the 3d scan comes with a file of texture, which is about 12 pages of texture map like I showed in the image, how can i map them with the point cloud i get?;) I really look forward to hearing from any of you amazing people . [image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ? Points can't display a material or texture (no volume or surface).